# How can I increase a scrollbar's width using CSS?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Is it possible to increase the width of a scrollbar on a `<div>` element placed inside the `<body>`?

I am not talking about the default scrollbar on the *browser itself*, this page runs in full screen mode and because the browser scrollbar never comes into picture, the inner `<div>` element has its own scrollbar.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you are talking about the scrollbar that automatically appears on a `div` with `overflow: scroll` (or `auto`), then no, that's still a native scrollbar rendered by the browser using normal OS widgets, and not something that can be styled(*).

Whilst you can replace it with a proxy made out of stylable divs and JavaScript as suggested by Matt, I wouldn't recommend it for the general case. Script-driven scrollbars never quite behave exactly the same as real OS scrollbars, causing usability and accessibility problems.

(*: Except for the IE colouring styles, which I wouldn't really recommend either. Apart from being IE-only, using them forces IE to fall back from using nice scrollbar images from the current Windows theme to ugly old Win95-style scrollbars.)

Comment: Hi bobince, You are right, its an overflow:scroll/auto scrollbar. I did try jScrollPane suggested by Matt but its degrading the performance of scrolling by a huge margin.

Comment: @TomasM  can you provide examples or a link?

Answer (score 149):

This can be done in WebKit-based browsers (such as Chrome and Safari) with only CSS:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    background: #ccc
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background: #888
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #eee
}​
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2aHeE/)**

---

**References:**

- [**Custom Scrollbars in WebKit | CSS-Tricks**](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)
- [**WebKit scrollbar demo from CSS-Tricks**](http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/)
- [**15 Different scrollbar configurations**](http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/overflow-scrollbar-combinations.html)

Comment: This doesn't work in Edge 40.15063.674.0 as of 10/24/2017. Grrr.

Comment: Well, **Edge** is **not** a **WebKit** based browser.

Comment: @Oliver you're never going to guess what happened.

Comment: This worked very well!

Comment: for firefox use:
* {
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}

Answer (score 19):

You can stablish specific toolbar for div

```
div::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 12px;
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

see demo in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/4xMUB/2/)

Comment: Not on Edge, not on Firefox

Answer (score 9):

This sets the scrollbar width:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;   // for vertical scroll bar
  height: 8px;  // for horizontal scroll bar
}

// for Firefox add this class as well
.thin_scroll{
  scrollbar-width: thin; // auto | thin | none | <length>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

If the scrollbar is not the browser scrollbar, then it will be built of regular HTML elements (probably `div`s and `span`s) and can thus be styled (or will be Flash, Java, etc and can be customized as per those environments).

The specifics depend on the DOM structure used.

Comment: Hi David, So whats the process to modify a scrollbar? The only CSS tags I know for styling are related to coloring only.

Comment: `#whateverElementyouAreFakingTheScrollbarWith { width: <length> }`

Answer (score 0):

My experience with trying to use CSS to modify the scroll bars is don't.  Only IE will let you do this.

Comment: webkit now allows this `::-webkit-scrollbar-[track|thumb|button|corner]`