# Styling scrollbar issue

Tags: html, css

Well, I'm trying to set width of scrollbar, using:

```
div.scrollabardiv::-webkit-scrollbar 
{
      width: 15px;
}
```

But this just removes my scrollbar for some reason.
Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wba111o/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-thumb`.

```css
div.scrollabardiv::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
  width: 15px;
}
```

As for the width of the scrollbar, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053220/css-scrollbar-width) post. Webkit browsers, like Chrome and Safari are able to render the width of the scrollbar using CSS, meaning you can't use the CSS HTML selector to modify that attribute. Here's how you can do it:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar 
{
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em
}
```

You'll need to define other properties, like `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`, `::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece`, and `::-webkit-scrollbar-button`, but you'll also be able to manipulate the width of the scrollbar now.

Hope that helps!