# Is It possible to set scrollbar track and Thumb width in IE(10+)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Thanks in Advance

we can customize scrollbar settings like width,color..etc easily in webkit browsers.But in IE, we are able to customize below settings and its working fine.

```
scrollbar-base-color: #CCCCCC;
scrollbar-3dlight-color: #CCCCCC;
scrollbar-highlight-color: #CCCCCC;
scrollbar-track-color: #ffffff;
scrollbar-arrow-color: #CCCCCC;
scrollbar-shadow-color: #CCCCCC;
scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: #CCCCCC;
```

But I want to set the width of scrollbar track by using CSS. Please let me know How to set scrollbar track and Thumb width in IE(10+).

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Scrollbar width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053220/css-scrollbar-width)

Comment: thanks...Could u share me a sample code to get it fixed