# Change width of the scrollbar in html <SELECT> list box

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

I am using `jQuery DatePicker` in my `application` and when I try to select the `YEAR` through `jQuery DatePicker`, `dropdown` appears with *list of year values*. What should be done to increase the `width` of the `scollbar` that appears in this `dropdown list` so that it can be `touched` and `dragged` (through plain `HTML/CSS/jQuery`).

[image]

I have used the exact jQuery datepicker.Below is the link for its demo.

https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/dropdown-month-year.html

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053220/css-scrollbar-width

Comment: if it is a native scrollbar then thats the browser job and you will have very limited options (if any) to do something about it.
unless you use a custom scrollbar plugin which will give you full control on its behaviour and style.