# How can I customize scrollbar width on IE using CSS?

Tags: html, css

```
id::-webkit-scrollbar

{ width: 12px; background-color: #F5F5F5; }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Scrollbar width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053220/css-scrollbar-width)

Answer (score 1):

you have these attributes for changing scrollbar stye in ie:

```
scrollbar-base-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-base-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-3dlight-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-highlight-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-track-color: #EBEBEB;
  scrollbar-arrow-color: black;
  scrollbar-shadow-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: #C0C0C0;
```

but you cant change the width in IE with CSS.
here are some jQuery plugins that you can change the width:

[jquery-scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

[js-scroll](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)