# Change default scrollbar width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the width of a default scrollbar. So far I've tried scrollbar-width which doesn't work on many browsers.::-webkit-scrollbar works but I can't seem to get the default look from it.

This is what I'm trying to style.

```css
.column1 {
  background-color:gray;
  padding: 19px 18px 49px 9px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="column1"><div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I increase a scrollbar's width using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053220/how-can-i-increase-a-scrollbars-width-using-css)

Comment: @LS_ I went through this and a person is saying that the default one cannot be styled. And someone else is saying that it can be since the last reply was on 2010

Comment: for a pure css solution your best option is [::-webkit-scrollbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar) but it won't work on firefox, otherwise look for a [js implementation](https://github.com/topics/custom-scrollbar)

Answer (score 0):

A fix to your issue will be by setting the width of the `::-webkit-scrollbar` to the size your want which will increase the size of the scrollbar.

```
.column1::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 11px;
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned, ::-webkit-scrollbar does change the width. But I can't seem to get the default scrollbar look.